# My submit button does not allow to be clicked on in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

This is my HTML

```
<form action="petDetails.php" id="animalInput">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <label for="dogName">Dog Name:</label><input id="dogName" type="text" name="dogName" />
       </li>
       <li>
          <label for="submit"></label><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enter dog name" name="submit" />
       </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I am trying to have the submit button be pressed and have an image under the button increase size. I also am just learning AJAX and I am unsure if that may be affecting it or maybe it is just my HTML.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: the `ul` doen't also have a closing tag `</ul>`

Comment: You'd need to post your JavaScript code to know what you are doing once that button is pressed. We need to know which event is being triggered or else it is difficult to assist you.

Comment: If you have an AJAX call in the JS part, then it's the HTML affecting the result. It's not that the button click wouldn't be executed, rather it's because the submit button submits the form, and aborts the pending AJAX call. As a result to the form submission, your server responds with a new page (presumably the same page already was open), and everything what was done on the previous page will be gone. To fix this, don't use submit button, use input type of button instead, and attach a click listener to it, which will call the AJAX.

Comment: Side note; as a general rule, you should avoid assigning the value of `submit` to an id or name of an element within a form.  This can bite you later with relation to some javascript operations.

Answer (score -1):

Your Implementation is correct and works for me, just open the developer tools of your browser, open the network tab, run your code snippet from below and click the submit button.
This will result in a request to the server, safari prints following output: `e.g. [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (petDetails.php, line 0)` which is as expected because the server side script `petDetails.php` is not present.

```html
<form action="petDetails.php" id="animalInput">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <label for="dogName">Dog Name:</label><input id="dogName" type="text" name="dogName" />
       </li>
       <li>
          <label for="submit"></label><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enter dog name" name="submit" />
       </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

To do the same with Ajax, you could do it like so:

```js
// Send data to backend via Ajax
function save_dog_name() {
    // Create XMLHttpRequest Object
    var http_handle = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Define data which should be send to the server
    var data = 'dogName=' + document.getElementById("dogName").value;
    // Open the connection
    http_handle.open('POST', "petDetails.php", true);
    // Send header to specify that data in request body will be urlencoded
    http_handle.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // Define what happens if the response has been received
    http_handle.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http_handle.readyState == 4 && http_handle.status == 200) {
            // Print response in case everything was OK
            console.log("Data has been received. Server response: " + http_handle.responseText);
        } else {
            // Print error message and response in case something went wrong
            console.log("An error occured. Server response: " + http_handle.status + " " + http_handle.statusText + " " + http_handle.responseText);
        }
    }
    http_handle.send(data);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="dogName">Dog Name:</label><input id="dogName" type="text" name="dogName" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="submit"></label><button onclick="save_dog_name()">Enter dog name</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For nice button design, you can use bootstrap, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#buttons